# How to get the graphical editor in Wso2 ESB Eclipse working?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to figure out how to open the graphical view of the Wso2 ESB, as described by Viraj in the blog here: http://sumuditha-viraj.blogspot.se/2012/05/introduction-to-wso2-developer-studio.html

I couldn't find any hint about these views in the core documentation for Developer Studio, so this is my last resort.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an ESB Configuration Project
2. Right click on the created ESB Configuration Project and select New => Synapse 
   Configuration.
3. Then follow the wizard and it will create an ESB diagram and open in the new ESB editor.
4. You can see the source in the source view of the Editor.

When you want to export the generated configurations, you need to create a C-App project and add select the created Graphical artifact from the list of artifact and export the C-App via IDE.

It will generate a CAR file with the generated configurations via the Graphical editor.

Thanks and Regards,

Harshana

Comment: Did you figure out how to import older esb artifacts to get them diagrammed? Maybe it doesn't work with things created earlier?

Comment: Older ESB artifact import capability is not there yet. But once we are done with Source to Diagram generation, you will be able to do it as well.

Answer (score 0):

The first obstacle was making sure the virtualbox was running the right version of the Wso2 Developer Studio, after upgrading it still didn't work.

The graphical view seem to be built on GMF which would mean GMF (http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=modeling.gmf) needs to be installed as an addon to eclipse.

Comment: Not really. WSO2 Developer Studio comes as a self contained installable P2 repository.  Therefore you don'e need to install GMF features on to your Eclipse instance.